# Java retrieving results from database

Tags: java, jdbc, arguments, prepared-statement, resultset

how do I retrieve a result set from the database using a prepared statement? I have no idea how to continue from my codes, I managed to get the query and the variables for the prepared statement and now I'm stucked at retrieving from database.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass field names as parameters. Only data can be passed like this. The condition

```
WHERE ?=?
--    ^
```

with substitutions `Field1` and `field1` will be interpreted literally, as

```
WHERE 'Field1'='field1' -- note the quotes around the values
```

If you would like to construct the condition from field names, you need to construct SQL string itself. For example, you could pass

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE %s=?
```

and use it as a format string for a [formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), passing `Field1` for the argument to substitute `%s`.

Be very careful for the names of fields not to be user-enterable: anything that becomes part of SQL string must come from a pool of constants in your program or its config file to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Oh i get it thanks ! But let's say if I want to display the result set out, how do i list them out from the fields that were passed ?

Comment: @dashblinkenlight Sorry i meant what if From another class it passed the query like "select Field1, Field2 from Table Where...." , How do i put the Field1 and Field2 (number of fields depending on query passed) into the prepared statement for me to retrieve the resultset?

Comment: @newbie95 Did you follow the link from the comment above?

Comment: Yes, I've done it but it prints out in the console, is there anyway to not print in console but return the result to another class?